# No se ve bien modalform con DataTable

Tags: modalform

Tengo un modalform con un DataTable pero se ve desplazado a la derecha y el DataTable sobresale:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el template:

```html
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">BUSQUEDA DE ARTICULO</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Que codigo CSS debo colocar para adaptar el cuadro al datatable y ocupar mas espacio?

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Caruso puedes probar con el siguiente código

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myModal').dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true, dialogClass: "popup_form", resizable: false, title: 'Estadísticas', width: 500, height: 500});
</script>
```

El dialogClass: "aquí pones tu css del dialog".

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Me dice: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function.pero gracias igual